# Convert CSV to txt file [powershell]

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a powershell script that edits a CSV and saves it. I then copy the CSV but save it as .txt

I was told that a rename from filename.csv to filename.txt isn't the correct way ( in my opinion it works ) , but is there another way to save a CSV as a TXT file "properly"

This is the current way I save the CSV as a .TXT

```
$csv = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\CSV Edit\20190522-Name-Num-Location-hey-hey.csv'
$path = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\CSV Edit\'
$pathdone = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\CSV Edit\done'

$txtfile = $date + $lastname + "-" + $lastxxx + "-" + $lastnum + "-" + $lastxxxtwo + "-" + $lastloc + "-" + $newid + ".txt"

# Save txt file as new format

Copy-Item "$csv" -Destination "$path$txtfile"
```

Reminder, my method does work and outputs a .TXT , but is there a different way to "properly" do it without renaming the "copy-item and saving it as a txt"

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path $csv -Header 'Stuff','City','Number','InStock'    # or add whatever headers you like
# get the first column as array of values
$column1 = $data.Stuff
# rotate the array values
switch ($column1.Count) {
    1 { Write-Host "Nothing to do here. There is only one row of data.."; break}
    2 { 
        # swap the values
        $data[0].Stuff,$data[1].Stuff = $data[1].Stuff,$data[0].Stuff
        break
    }
    default {
        $newColumn1 = @($column1[-1]; $column1[0..($column1.Count -2)])
        # re-write the first column in the data
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $newColumn1.Count; $i++) {
            $data[$i].Stuff = $newColumn1[$i]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what is your colleague's reasoning for why that isn't "correct" or "proper"?  I think it's important, too, to distinguish between a "text file" and a "`.txt` file".  You can take _any_ file and give it a `.txt` extension; whether or not the extension accurately describes the contents is another matter.  Otherwise, CSV is a text-based format and so, by definition, it is a subset of text files and, therefore, text in its own right.  It'd be the same as asking how to save a `.ps1`, `.ini`, or `.css` file as text, to give just a few examples.

Comment: @bacon , well we take this csv file and rename it as .txt , now we load this .txt into a scraper. My colleague thinks that " & " and " apostrophe " is not being handled correctly and causes an error. ( we had question marks in the the csv/txt (both) appear out of nowhere ) He thought my script that edits and renames the csv as a .txt is causing this. Now I made a new CSV with just 9 lines of what we edit and i added ( & and a apostrophe ) to see if it would cause the error ( it did not ) ..he is still convinced that it is because of renaming .csv as .txt instead of "saving as .txt"

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with either the script that's editing the CSV (the question marks suggest an incorrect text encoding) or the scraper itself, yet your colleague is attributing it to the edited CSV → text "conversion". Have you tried running a diff on the CSV before and after the edits to see exactly what's getting changed? If you're using PowerShell cmdlets to perform the edits note that they normalize their output; for example, if you run `"First, Second, Third\`n1, 2, 3" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` the output gets quoted but loses the space after commas.

Comment: The whole text encoding thing is why he thinks it is the script, but...I have tested the script with the & sign and ' sign , neither cause the issue and those are the only special characters in our CSV that we edit. I even test with a small sample size of lines ( 9 lines ) and out of those none have a issue when the script edits it. The only thing the script does it open the CSV, change the first column by moving the very last item in the first column to the very top. then I save the csv..and rename it as a .txt ... I added this portion to the Original post so you can see how it edits.

Answer (score 3):

A CSV *is* a text file following a formatting convention. The extension just tells what to expect, Comma Separated Values.
In principle there is nothing wrong with saving it as txt. You will not loose any information. It's just less clear from the beginning that it is still just a file with comma separated values. So please, no headaches :)

Comment: Just for clarity... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Is there a method to save it as a .txt using export-csv ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can open it with every text editor as is. The extension is more a Windows thing used in the old days to get what program to use to open it.